# Set default accounts for truffle like hardhat

Tags: truffle

I'm using the truffle suite against a custom network. This network returns an empty list in response to `eth_accounts`. So I need to feed the truffle with default accounts (I mean default private keys) in the configuration file just like [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#accounts). Is it possible in truffle?

I also set `from` in `networks` in `truffle-config.js` but after that truffle sends an `eth_sendTransaction` instead of `eth_sendRawTransaction` and again my custom network doesn't support `eth_sendTransacton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure truffle to use [@truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/hdwallet-provider#readme).

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const mnemonicPhrase = "..."; // Use the wallet mnemonic phrase

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    mynetwork: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider({
          mnemonic: {
            phrase: mnemonicPhrase
          },
          providerOrUrl: "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID",
        }),
    }
  }
};
```